# Flexible Space With Image With ViewPager Tab Activity

Tags: java, android, github, material-design

i want to implement **FlexibleSpaceWithImageWithViewPagerTabActivity.java** in my application. i mean i want to achieve behavior that is shown by this above class. It shows flexible space with image and viewpager with tabs, and has smooth scroll of actionbar with recyclerView.

[Here](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/FlexibleSpaceWithImageWithViewPagerTabActivity.java) is the code of this class.

i am trying to implement this class. Anybody please help me, how can i use this class or can make my own class having similar behavior.

i have imported this class from **[this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)** library using gradle. But don't know how to use it.

Thanks in Advance